# How to make a more than 1 clause using array value in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have some query, I want make that query have a more than 1 condition but I have some problem, I wanna know how to make a more than 1 condition using an array.

Code Like this :

```
$array = ['1', '2', '3'];

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('my_table');
$this->db->where('my_field', $array);

$result = $this->db->get();
return $result->result();
```

but when I see the result is, data just a showing only condition in index '0' in my array not execute all my index in array, how can I make my all value array join to my clause condition.

***If my explanation is incomprehensible, I apologize, and you can ask me again, Thank You***

Comment: You may need to use `where_in ` instead of `where` .

Comment: okay that's work Thanks a lot, I must read the documentation more..hehe

Answer (score 1):

You may try it. I think it will solve your problem.

```
$array = ['1', '2', '3'];
$builder = $db->table('my_table');
$builder->select('*');
$builder->whereIn('my_field', $names);
$result = $builder->get();
```